# How do HTML forms work when there is both a submit button and a JS function call which submits?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, form-submit

I currently have a form with a submit button, but this button also has a function tied to the `onclick` event. This function will run some code and submit the form at the end.

```
<script>
function submitForm() {
    var form = document.getElementById("form");
    // Do stuff.
    form.submit();
}
</script>

<form id="form" method="post">
    <button type="submit" value="Save" onclick="submitForm()">Save</button>
</form>
```

As can be seen, the button itself would submit the form as it is the `submit` type, but it is also going to call a function which would do some things and then submit the form as well.

Thus, I am unsure how things will work out here; will the form be submitted two times? Should the button be changed to a normal button instead, and let the function alone handle the submission?

Comment: Since `form.submit()` reloads the page, the default form submission won't happen.

Comment: But if the function didn't reload the page, the form would submit after the function returns.